# Get value from javascript and php return two value in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm a newbie in JAVASCRIPT and PHP. I'm sorry if this question is already solve in other problem. I just need the link that disame in my problem.This is my code:

All I want is their a code that `xmlhttp.responseText` return two value of my `empnum` and `fname` to their respective `td id="erroremonum"` and `td ="errorfname"`.

All I get in this only the combination of two echo.

My table in `index.php`:

```
<tr>
<td >Employee Number</td>
<td>:</td>
<td width="150px"><input type="text" name="empnum" id="empnum" maxlength="4"></td>  
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td id="errorempnum"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td >Firstname</td>
<td>:</td>
<td width="150px"><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" ></td> 
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td id="errorfname"></td></tr>


<tr>
<td><center><button id="submit" style="margin-top:20px" onClick="reg()">Submit</button></center></td>
<td colspan="2"><button id="cancel" style="margin-top:20px">Cancel</button></td>
</tr>
```

In my script:

```
function reg(empnum1)
{
var empnum = document.getElementById("empnum").value;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } 
            else { // code for IE6, IE5
                     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            if(xmlhttp.responseText)
            {
            document.getElementById("errorempnum").style.color = "Red";
            document.getElementById("errorempnum").innerHTML= "*Employee number is exist!";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("errorempnum").innerHTML="";
            }
        }
         }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","checkempnum.php?empnum1="+checkemp+"&fname1="+fname,true);
      xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Check `empnum` or `fname` is exist in database `check.php`:

```
$empnum = intval($_GET['empnum1']);
$empnum = mysql_real_escape_string($empnum);
$fname = strval($_GET['fname1']);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($empnum);

$checkempnum= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM systemuser WHERE employeenumber='{$empnum}'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($checkempnum);
if($num_rows == 1)
{
 echo "employee number exist";
}
$checkfname= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM systemuser WHERE firstname='{$fname}'");
$num_rows1 = mysql_num_rows($checkfname);
if($num_rows1 == 1)
{
 echo "firstname exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your form an id of for example `id="myForm"` and use [Jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var empid = $("#empnum").val();
    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    dataGet = 'empnum='+empid+'&fname='+fname;
    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            data:dataGet,
            url:'checkempnum.php',
            success:function(data) {
              $("#errorempnum").html(data);             
            }
       });    
});
```

Comment: sir when i put two variable $("#errorempnum").html(erroremp);
  $("#errorfname").html(errorfname); their combine.. how can i seperate them  when loading...

and their a message show success full.. even i dont have sucess .. how can i remove that ?..